# Acumatica: change functionality of private method

Tags: c#, overriding, acumatica

I'm relatively new at Acumatica, so some of this might be stuff that's relatively simple. The problem I'm having is that I need to change the functionality of what happens when an invoice that has a multiple installment plan is released. I think the method that needs to be modified is the CreateInstallments method in the ARReleaseProcess class. This method is private though so I'm not able to override it in the extended class. Is there some workaround way to be able to either change the source code or change how the function is called? I've looked through T200 and T300 and neither of them talks about this problem. Is this something that has a fix, or is there just no solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to override the private method. You would need to see if that method makes any other calls to see if you can override them or work with the cache for the row/field being inserted/updated by using RowPersisted,  FieldUpdated, etc.